# Is there way to trace through all java files in intellij or other IDE?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

When I try to trace through code, intellij debugger seems to skip stepping through some classes such as java.lang.ref.Reference. For the purpose of learning how Jdk works, I wanted to include all files even the ones in java.lang.ref.*. I am using Intellij debugger. Any ideas about what IDE or configurations that show all files stepped through?

example code I use to debug (wanted to see JDK behavior for instantiation of objects):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]x){
        Pojo p = new Pojo("hello123");
    }
}
class Pojo{
    public String value = null;
    public Pojo(String value){
        this.value=value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the JDKs implementation of creating objects is not java code meaning you cannot step into it using the java debugger. You could try using tools like gdb if you want to debug native code (but you may want to build the JDK from source for that).

Comment: Just checked, search for "Stepping" in Settings and remove check mark from "Do not step into the classes"

Comment: ah ok, when I installed fresh intellij everything works with debugger now.

Comment: 2nd part of question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70434498/debugging-guts-of-jdk